# On Eclipse Mars, I can't see 1.8 in the compiler compliance level menu

Tags: java-8, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse Mars and I can't see 1.8 in the compiler compliance level menu.

[image]

Prehaps, it is because I used this option to import all my plugins from my Eclipse Kepler installation. Maybe it also import preferences that causes this problem.
[image]

I added the jdk 1.8 in the Installed JREs.
I tried to delete the .preferences folder and restart my eclipse but I still have the problem.

Any ideas?

EDIT : I tried to check for updates but no updates were found

Comment: I don't know exactly, but have you tried Help -> Check for updates? Probably by copying the Kepler plugins you downgraded some of them...

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes and "No updates were found".

Comment: Can you list your installed plugins (help -> installation details) and maybe a screenshot of java -> installed JREs -> execution environments

Comment: Sure! [Installed plugins](http://i.imgur.com/Wk2RrvH.jpg), [Execution envionments](http://i.imgur.com/bFV4pkL.jpg)

Comment: Just use a clean eclipse installation. Problem solved.

Comment: have you changed -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 in eclipse.ini? Or specifying the -vm argument as suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Probably it was because I originally installed Eclipse Kepler (which doesn't support java 1.8. compiler) and then updated it to Luna first and then to Mars. I had to completely uninstall Eclipse and reinstall newest version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the appropriate java version in the project's/ build path first

[image: jdk selection]

If you want to apply it globally you not only have to add a 1.8 JRE but also select it as default.

Comment: I tried this but I don't have [this option in the execution environment](http://i.imgur.com/Ufgwogy.png). Despite I have the 1.8 jdk in the [installed JREs](http://i.imgur.com/u0EPRtT.png)..

Comment: You could just try using `alternate JRE` instead of the execution environment. although the environment definitely should be there in mars.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shortcut to start eclipse, edit it and add `-vm [path-to-jdk-1.8]/jre/Javaw.exe` after the path to eclipse.exe .
You can also add the code to your eclipse.ini but make sure it is the very first line. Afterwards you might be able to chose 1.8 in the global compliance level